# How to find correlation between two images

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

I need to find correlation between two images, using numpy, but basic math only. I have the problem:"***
IndexError: index 5434 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5434***". And i have a code. Tell me what to do, pls.

```
img = PIL.Image.open("SR1.png").convert("L")
im = numpy.array(img)
img2 = PIL.Image.open("SR61.png").convert("L")
im2 = numpy.array(img2)
np.array(im,dtype=float)
np.array(im2,dtype=float)
import math
import cmath
def correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n) : 
    sum_X = 0
    sum_Y = 0
    sum_XY = 0
    squareSum_X = 0
    squareSum_Y = 0


    i = 0
    for i in range(n) : 
        sum_X = sum_X + X[i]
        sum_Y = sum_Y + Y[i] 
        sum_XY = sum_XY + X[i] * Y[i] 
        squareSum_X = squareSum_X + X[i] * X[i] 
        squareSum_Y = squareSum_Y + Y[i] * Y[i] 

        i = i + 1

    corr = (n * sum_XY - sum_X * sum_Y)/(cmath.sqrt((n * squareSum_X - sum_X * sum_X)* (n * squareSum_Y - sum_Y * sum_Y))) 
    return corr


X = im.flatten()
Y = im2.flatten()


n = len(X) 


print ('{0:.6f}'.format(correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n)))
```

[image: Corr coef]

Comment: O.K.
I changed something

Comment: `len(X) == len(Y)`?

Comment: First of all get rid of `i=0` and `i = i + 1` since you have the for-loop.

Comment: @AndreasK.
@MykolaZotko
Thx, guys
But know "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars"
Because of this i have corr coef -243,..
It`s not good ))
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Where did you get the formula for corr? Can you show the source?

Comment: @AndreasK. I added the picture into the question, look at it,pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized version of your function:

```
import numpy as np

def correlationCoefficient(X, Y):
    n = X.size
    sum_X = X.sum()
    sum_Y = Y.sum()
    sum_XY = (X*Y).sum()
    squareSum_X = (X*X).sum()
    squareSum_Y = (Y*Y).sum()
    corr = (n * sum_XY - sum_X * sum_Y)/(np.sqrt((n * squareSum_X - sum_X * sum_X)* (n * squareSum_Y - sum_Y * sum_Y))) 
    return corr
```

It is also important to normalize your image arrays to avoid overflow:

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open("1.jpg").convert("L")
im1 = np.array(img1)/255

img2 = Image.open("2.jpg").convert("L")
im2 = np.array(img2)/255

print ('{0:.6f}'.format(correlationCoefficient(im1, im2)))
```

Comment: So, now it will be "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (96,124) (38,143) "

Comment: @Антон Тугусов Are your images of the same size? They should be of the same shape. If not then maybe resize them.

Comment: But, if i want to find corr coef between images not of the same size. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: mb you know, how to depict corr coef on image
it`s will be my output: png image with correlation
do you have any idea?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. The formula you gave is for x and y of the same size. So maybe you need something else.

Comment: but what about image with result of correlation? i mean my output

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `corrcoef` in numpy to find Peason correlation. First you need to `flatten` both image arrays:

```
np.corrcoef(im1.flatten(), im2.flatten())
```

Comment: Now i have another problem :)